# PHP & MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an assignment for school and I'm trying to run the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE teams
(city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
nickname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
division VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO teams (city, nickname, division)
VALUES ('Pittsburgh', 'Penguins', 'Metropolitan'), ('New York', 'Rangers', 'Metropolitan'), ('New York', 'Islanders', 'Metropolitan'), ('Philadelphia', 'Flyers', 'Metropolitan'), ('New Jersey', 'Devils', 'Metropolitan'),
('Montreal', 'Canadiens', 'Atlantic'), ('Boston', 'Bruins', 'Atlantic'), ('Toronto', 'Maple Leafs', 'Atlantic'), ('Ottawa', 'Senators', 'Atlantic'), ('Buffalo', 'Sabres', 'Atlantic'),
('Washington', 'Capitals', 'Metropolitan'), ('Detroit', 'Red Wings', 'Atlantic'), ('Carolina', 'Hurricanes', 'Metropolitan'), ('Tampa Bay', 'Lightning', 'Atlantic'), ('Florida', 'Panthers', 'Atlantic'), ('Columbus', 'Blue Jackets', 'Metropolitan');
```

For some reason when I run it I get Error 1215 regarding a foreign key constraint.
Any ideas?

Update: Apparently I need to remove the constraint in the sql, but this still leaves me confused as to how I'm suppose to do that.

Comment: I don't believe you got a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` error from the above 2 statements. Are you sure you're not getting it from another statement? Try running them 1 at a time.

Comment: I've been working with this for a few days...I've ran them separately and it still shows up as Error 1215 so I'm at a complete loss and have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Please post the *complete* text of the error message.

Comment: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Your code does not attempt to add a foreign key constraint, though.

Comment: I'm aware of that, that's the problem. I don't know how to fix it so it accepts the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way those queries should lead to a foreign key constraint.

However, you should be defining a primary key for your table, even if it's a composite one.

If you want to venture into the realm of "good" DB design, your database should also be normalized and consist of separate tables from the team, division and city.
This may well be outside the scope of your assignment though.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix it so it stops giving me the error, or any ideas as to why it would be giving me the error?